Question regarding functional equations involving series
This question is regarding the following problem.
Let $f(x) = x + f(x-1)$ for $\forall x \in R$. If $f(0) = 1$, find $f(100)$
I found out the following pattern in the question
$$f(1) = 1 + f(0) = 2$$
$$f(2) = 2 + f(1) = 4$$
$$f(3) = 3 + f(2) = 7$$
So the series formed is $1, 2, 4, 7, \ldots$
Now,
$$S = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + \ldots + f(n-1)$$
$$S = 0 + 1 + 2 + 4 + \ldots + f(n-2) + f(n-1)$$
Subtracting these two we get
$$f(n-1) = (1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + \ldots + n \text{ terms }$$
Now,
$$f(n-1) = 1 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
However in my textbook it is given tat
$$f(n-1) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
Is this wrong? or is their a reason for this any help would be highly appreciated!

The functional equation is $f(n) = n+f(n-1)$ and $f(0)=1$. You consider the series $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)$. Using the functional equation, we see that
$$
S_n = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+f(k-1)) = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} f(k) =  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  + S_{n-1}
$$
since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Thus $S_n-S_{n-1} = f(n-1) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
Thus it seems that where you go wrong is in applying the equation $f(n)=n+f(n-1)$ to $f(0)$ in the sum but not noting that it implies $f(-1)=1$ rather than $0$. This is where $\Sigma$-notation, once you get used to it, can make it easier ensure you consider these cases properly.
